# Where are Excel templates saved?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, templates

I have an Excel template that I use on my work desktop. It is saved in the location specified by this page [Where are my custom templates?](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Where-are-my-custom-templates-88ed77ca-df34-49e9-9087-3f01ae296e6e) I copied the template to my work laptop, into the same location as it is on my work desktop. I'm using Office 365 for Business, on both machines. When I try to create a new spreadsheet, using the template, as specified by Microsoft's documentation, Excel cannot find it.

Why not?

Comment: The Microsoft link provided is an article on how to change where the new office looks for personal templates. The article never mentions the new office's default location for personal templates. These instructions show how to change where the new office looks when the personal templates button is clicked. The path provided in the article is to the old office's default location. Using this path to configure the new office change's the new office to look there instead of the new default location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your personal templates are supposed to be inside the folder
`C:\Users\YOUR-NAME\Documents\Custom Office Templates`.

Open in Excel the menu *File > Options > Save*, and ensure that your folder
is entered inside the field *Default personal templates location*.
If it's not, then set the field to your folder and click OK.

Comment: Ah, so the link I gave from Microsoft's website wasn't accurate, or my understanding of what it said is faulty. Thank you for correcting me!